# how to merge all opencover coverage files into one coverage file

Tags: code-coverage, opencover, reportgenerator

I am looking how to merge the test projects coverage file into one coverage file for .net core using Coverlet. I know we can do it using Report Generator but the output format of the Report generator is in Xml format which is not understandable by SonarQube. So I could like to know is there a way to get one Coverage file which can be in opencover format using Coverlet.

I have created a coverage files for multiple test projects using Coverlet package. My question is can we able to merge all coverage files into one coverage file without using Report Generator. Can I have an example how to do it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*ReportGenerator* is not able to generate an *OpenCover* file as output.
But *ReportGenerator* is capable to generate a *Cobertura* file with all input files merged.
*Sonarcube* should be able to handle the *Cobertura* file.

Perhaps you need a plugin:
 - http://www.sonarplugins.com/cobertura
 - https://github.com/galexandre/sonar-cobertura
 - http://allsolutions-hd.weebly.com/blog/how-to-integrate-cobertura-with-sonar-for-code-coverage-step-by-step-demonstrations